# vim - remapping >> << (indent commands)

Tags: vim, indentation, remap

I would love to map << and >> to single keys to speed up my workflow,  but I can't find any info on how to write the remap in my vimrc. Any idea how I can get my remap on?

Comment: Do you really want to remap them? After the first indentation via `>>`, you can press `.` to repeat the action. Just about as good as remapping to a single keystroke.

Comment: In visual mode, a single `<` or `>` performs the indentation already.

Comment: note that in insert mode CTRL-T and CTRL-D indent and deindent respectively.

Comment: @Michael, I know, I'm totally lazy. There's just something exhausting about hitting the same key twice all day to initiate indents (even if I repeat them with . After). I figure the answers below will still save me hundreds of keystrokes a day. (Yes, I deal with that much markup). Thanks for the tips everyone!

Comment: @tester if you're dealing with a lot of HTML or XML and you find yourself constantly indenting stuff, hopefully you're using `=` to fix indentation as well...

Comment: yeah I do, it's more where I run into something like a two row set of brackets I want to organize and it's the same amount of work to highlight them and == as it would be to >> the two rows (like if it only needed one indentation, == would be the same as >>). You're totally right about lots of html auto indenting with == though. It just always seemed strange that it had to be >> instead of > in command mode when it's a single in every other mode.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for `:noremap`:

```
:noremap > >>
:noremap < <<
```

If you just use `:map`, you of course get recursively defined function, which is hilarious. (`^C` will stop it.) The `:noremap` variant doesn't recursively expand mappings.

Answer (score 12):

The other responses given answer your immediate question. I would just like to suggest that you remap that to indent and dedent to  and  respectively, in both normal and visual modes (making sure to add `gv` to reselect in visual selection mode):

```
nnoremap <TAB> >>
nnoremap <S-TAB> <<
vnoremap <TAB> >gv
vnoremap <S-TAB> <gv
```

In insert mode of course, as you probably might know already, you can just use <kbd>Ctrl-t</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> to indent/dedent.

Comment: I can't exit from visual mode with escape when I use this keybindings. Is there any solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

I find these to be the most natural indentation keymaps for both normal and visual modes

```
" Normal mode  
nnoremap > >>
nnoremap < <<

" Visual mode
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
```